# PHP mail() email address is different from the email being sent

Tags: php, email, sendmail, send

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emails showing from host.myserver.com instead of mydomain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439840/emails-showing-from-host-myserver-com-instead-of-mydomain-com)

Not sure if this will make sense, but when I try to send an email from russell.harrower@mydomain.com it says sentby root@host.mydomain.com

Is there anyway to fix this?

Yahoo Results.

```
From iNcard Thu Sep 15 20:25:29 2011
X-Apparently-To: russell.harrower@yahoo.com via 98.138.87.158; Thu, 15 Sep 2011 20:25:32 -0700
Return-Path: <icard-lifestyle-guide@incard.com.au>
Received-SPF: none (domain of incard.com.au does not designate permitted sender hosts)
X-YMailISG: lo3RhWoWLDv_WHz3JN9HmYtpybG2PDVs8qfPdALeMm06q6Va
 7_JLFvrtF3ZMrNnWTt.LFkzfH8epmIbIXDqmvgfBfiEV5bgtYB.7u4Ct17Dx
 gXTX0gNkH7_Ad9Im0fuFYp6bB1b8N4ymRJ86dFjEsCaEEwB7Q8_5cZzMZJW9
 gZcRui_aVjfybJxiClzRlb8xgCsOsf1qYjJx5dF__GX9UcZqIhC9XOQgj8bf
 VEQKZMSuXGT8TAblfeAE0V39fQEPOOjBEMzYYMf7Mch8jjD.RlV4IOBVPZBF
 jNAthv0bCKIQICb7JBEVe03A9C33MzIYyY_DlGugFBdr9I3r19PZKutv2Lsd
 e7FkpZ6li8rd3Em5wN3blqWGP.pgtxnOAw4klakMQbxQ9MuRPcvLoVT_G1Ab
 .eLzBJnHwojtG3.nsCahq1mxq88GsG9ZeAqaN74Fn1Cs8zGKx2dIndp_8lPt
 CH_M4q5DXvjpQmCszDbICAKXJFX9VaQFsjjOMUVwJemDlGlSm.N0xUb78MX7
 WFXZyht5tGLsuJcNR8qazP1DoHPt0Z4yKNE.SGOpCdV.aqyWaU3Z84rFodob
 aR0ZfXg411De2TyOw3G1d4OPIST_fNgVHslC1gaeGQc5jRQur37E.5J4cuYl
 PTKhZKh2WKjTACJaLauMzurW3da7f_46iurJLNm_kUfCbNUwjTjfcjfm7zcC
 CFYlgMQ.uwIyFEZ9wfTFMKhdktB1Pt6_OJZ2AMDgfVbkWsGhzSPpzGBW8wIN
 ObOPKdwaDDBgGHeBR2om9uTq1nL.O3KvX946mgYMhbcBdDQAXyiW.9I2882M
 6a.0YjE12tfEzrmYAWCijJQw7uOlfuDYsBO2FOEYRzfgvnHB5hoTHJb3NHz5
 3sIXnnIfAB6sbh7psVd9Hp.nE6bmaqQr4CubIWJanYv6.o5sxKBXVQEuHFTA
 3s0AAP3FlW8Qpsj_i2SybgmHBvFx_.a0sM2Qh6p3d0D7zQZLIwzYS0nA6wRL
 GtM_krFeie2fRApV7s.GIxyn2vauuypWFzF.vKRaxLLfsYnLljcOYy9EXeQC
 ahCxNHg9lppRMZNvPyTFBpcj1mle32pZkWE5HQyxr_aNnz3a69RPoBnQNvi3
 W4zl_CsWcBxqxSdA15i2Kkh0HDgO6THcfq1Vwaf89buHwqFo2RnRcumB1Q7W
 vRxBG9ci..an6iKSaPIGEvTOkwIhBbn17sL62hliHa6kVnnv5iIGdiPHZYxb
 BQh3oDtYkL8i.ICgkpQW4OCXj007fmizFgQvO1f1DYxAkbCbztbIHzzAv5Ae
 kQmxBYTDfOMUmfbU996gPH25NYiVuF1z_eY6CB0BFozwv7gnadJBfGhzi6H2
 XndEqKkhYXmSQ1.ixvAn78xYt8eJwi0C3Y0CRt5qbM84S0M0dbI-
X-Originating-IP: [173.199.158.72]
Authentication-Results: mta1011.mail.ac4.yahoo.com  from=host.realcashback.com.au; domainkeys=neutral (no sig);  from=incard.com.au; dkim=neutral (no sig)
Received: from 127.0.0.1  (EHLO host.realcashback.com.au) (173.199.158.72)
  by mta1011.mail.ac4.yahoo.com with SMTP; Thu, 15 Sep 2011 20:25:32 -0700
Received: from realcas by host.realcashback.com.au with local (Exim 4.69)
    (envelope-from <icard-lifestyle-guide@incard.com.au>)
    id 1R4P3R-0006qu-DD
    for russell.harrower@yahoo.com; Thu, 15 Sep 2011 22:25:29 -0500
To: russell.harrower@yahoo.com
Subject: iNcard Eftpos Lifestyle Guide
X-PHP-Script: realcashback.com.au/system/classes/core.php for 61.88.97.122
From: iNcard <russell.harrower@incard.com.au>
Reply-To: iNcard <russell.harrower@incard.com.au>
Message-ID:< icard-lifestyle-guide@incard.com.au>
X-Mailer: PHP v5.2.17
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; boundary="75434adf143cb37a87b1e10e2f08ffd4"
Sender:  <realcas@host.realcashback.com.au>
Date: Thu, 15 Sep 2011 22:25:29 -0500
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - host.realcashback.com.au
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - yahoo.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [500 32002] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - incard.com.au
X-Source: /usr/bin/php
X-Source-Args: /usr/bin/php /home/realcas/public_html/system/classes/core.php 
X-Source-Dir: realcashback.com.au:/public_html/system/classes
Content-Length: 8054
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending mail like this and see if it works for you:

```
<?php
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, "-fyou@yourdomain.com");
?>
```

Do you have a "From: you@yourdomain.com" in the $headers as well?

Comment: Yes I have the from, and sadly nope that did not work
Could it be that the domain I want to send it from is not on the same server?

Comment: If the 5th parameter with the -f didn't work, then you will probably not be able to send using your email address, it is being blocked by your host.  Usually -f should fix the problem you described.  Also, do you know if your host is windows or linux, the -f only works with sendmail

Comment: it is being sent but its still showing as root@host.realcashback.com.au i'll post some things above

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using the `mail()` function. You need to set the `From:` header.

Taken from the documentation:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This will say the email was sent from `webmaster@exmaple.com` in your case, the `$headers` line you'd use is:

```
$headers = 'From: russell.harrower@mydomain.com' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Yes that is what I am doing, but when I try to send it, it shows in gmail the word via and then root@mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you are using windows or unix.

Windows, use the (badly named) sendmail_from entry in php.ini

Unix it depends on your MTA... generally it involves setting the correct flags in sendmail_path again in php.ini
but some MTAs will allow you to putenv() variables that cause the "sendmail" MUA injection to use your custom SMTP envelope sender.

Edit -additional:

Ok, so your MTA is exim, and the answer lies with your exim configuration.  You need to tell exim that PHP is allowed to set the envelope sender address (-f notroot@someone.com). Read this: http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_5.html#SEC38